# Join variety of two non-parallel lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is an exercise in the [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521691419) by Hassett.

Let $l(1)$, $l(2)\in \mathbb{A}^3(\mathbb{R})$ be disjoint non-parallel lines. Show that Join($l(1)$, $l(2)$) = $ \mathbb{A}^3(\mathbb{R}) $.

I can see that it must be true. The problem is to show that for an arbitrary point $p\in \mathbb{A}^3(\mathbb{R}) $, we can always find points $p_1\in l(1)$ and $p_2\in l(2)$, such that $p\in \overline{p_1 p_2}$.

Take the affine plane through $p$ and $l(1)$, it generally will intersect with $l(2)$, right? Denote the intersection point as $p_2$, then $\overline{p p_2}$ intersects with $l(1)$ at some point $p_1$, and this means $p\in \overline{p_1 p_2}$.

But how to make a rigorous proof?